# Changing style properties inside 'click' events in multiple elements, using if statements

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

I have a simple todo list (`<ul>`). When user clicks `<li>`, the textDecoration property changes to "line-through". I want to be able to "undo" this somehow. Here's my code...

```
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
lis.forEach(li => li.addEventListener('click', taskHandler));

function taskHandler(e) {
    const li = e.target;
    if ((li.style.textDecoration = 'none')) {
        li.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
        console.log(`${li.textContent} is done`);
    } else {
        li.style.textDecoration = 'none';
        console.log(`${li.textContent} is undone`);
    }
}
```

My question is : **why `else` block doesn't work ? And how do I fix this code ?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a single `=` assignment operator to compare:

```
if ((li.style.textDecoration = 'none'))
```

Replace it with either `==` or `===`:

```
if ((li.style.textDecoration == 'none'))
```

Also, not sure why the double `(())` parenthesis?

```
if (li.style.textDecoration === 'none')
```

Should work fine.